# Worst category with first isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, big-list

I am no expert in category theory, but from VIII of [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf) I learnt that

> In an abelian category every $A\xrightarrow{\phi}B$ can be decomposed into \begin{equation}A\twoheadrightarrow C\cong D\rightarrowtail B.
> \end{equation}

So in abelian categories, every morphism can be decomposed into a epimorphism, followed by an isomorphism, and then an monomorphism, which is the so-called first isomorphism theorem in some famous categories $\operatorname{Set}$, $\operatorname{Grp}$, $\operatorname{Ring}$ and $R\operatorname{-Mod}$.

However, we notice that $\operatorname{Ring}$ is not actually abelian modules and $\operatorname{Grp}$ is not even additive. So the axioms for abelian categories are not actually necessary for the first isomorphism.

I am asking whether there is a natural *minimum* requirement for a category to have the first isomorphism. If there is no such requirement, then maybe someone can share some *bad* categories in which one still has the first isomorphism.

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's the `first (isomorphism theorem)`, not the `(first isomorphism) theorem`.

Comment: I've fixed the arrows: double check that this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the arrows. I am just using 'first isomorphism' as a short version for 'first isomorphism theorem'.

Answer (score 6):

The first isomorphism theorem says more than this (e.g. it says something about kernels), but if all you want is the existence (and not necessarily uniqueness) of [epi-mono factorizations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(epi,+mono)+factorization+system), then any [regular category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category) has this property. This includes categories of models of finitary algebraic theories.

If you want uniqueness, note that uniqueness actually *fails* for $\text{Ring}$...

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem says (essentially) that every morphism factors as an effective epimorphism followed by a monomorphism, which is precisely what happens in a regular category.

Comment: Is there a stronger theorem that does say something about Kernels in abelian categories?